# What is the remainder of the division $\frac{2^{82}}{7}$?

Tags: number-theory

I tried this in the following way

step 1:- `(2)^2*41 /7`

step 2:- `(2)^2*41 / 2^2 + 3`

step 3:- let us assume `x = 2^2`

step 4:-  then `x^41 / x+3`

step 5:- Using Remainder theorem, x = -3

```
F(-3) = (-3)41
```

Step 6:- As the last digits of 3 repeats for every four power
          last digit of 3^41 = last digit of 3^1

```
so, (-3)^1 = -3
```

step 7:-  Divisor is added to get a positive number

```
   -3+7 = 4
```

The answer which I calculated is 4, but the correct answer was 2.  Could any help me out?? I am trying to solve this through remainder theorem.

Comment: $2^{2^{41}}\not= 2^{82}$

Comment: $2^{82}\equiv x\ (\mod{7})$, $x=2$

Comment: @AMR It's not 2^2^41.  It is 2^2*41

Comment: @ParveenKumar OK. It's better to write it as 2^(2*41)

Comment: Your mistake is that you cannot just look at the last digit of $3^{41}$. The last digit is ok, if you want remainder after division by ten, but it is not ok, when dividing by seven.

Answer (score 4):

You're seeking to find $$2^{82}\mod 7$$

Since $7$ is prime and $7\not\mid 2$, we can use Fermat's little theorem that tells us that $$2^6\equiv 1 \mod 7$$

(this actually is not that hard to see, $64-1=63=7\times 9$)

But $82=13\times 6+4$. So we obtain this is $$2^4\mod 7=2$$

Comment: In the solution he has used the denominator as 7 = ``(2^3) -1`` and got the solution ``2``.  But I have used 7 = ``(2^2) + 3`` and got ``4``. Is there anything wrong in using ``(2^2) + 3``??

Comment: @Praveenkumar I don't know what you did, so I cannot tell.

Comment: @Praveenkumar: Nothing wrong with that, but you made a mistake while calculating the remainder of $3^{41}$.

Answer (score 3):

$2^3\equiv 1 (\mbox{mod } 7) $. So you have $2^{82}=2\cdot(2^3)^{27}\equiv 2\cdot 1^{27}\equiv 2 (\mbox{mod } 7)$. So the answer is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that what you call *the remainder theorem* says the following:

---

**Theorem.** Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, and let $a$ be an integer. When we are carrying out the polynomial long division
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x-a}
$$
the constant remainder term is equal to $f(a)$. In other words, there exists a polynomial $g(x)$ with integer coefficients such that
$$
f(x)=g(x)(x-a)+f(a).
$$

---

In view of this I would do the following. Let $x=8$, so $7=x-1$. Then 
$$
2^{82}=2^{3\cdot27+1}=2\cdot(2^3)^{27}=2x^{27}.
$$
The remainder theorem tells us that the remainder of the division $\dfrac{2x^{27}}{x-1}$ (evaluating at $x=1$) is thus
$2\cdot1^{27}=2$.

---

I agree with others that this is easier with Little Fermat and its cousins, but it sounds like you haven't covered those yet?

Comment: Can't we use the expression in the form of x+1 instead of using x-1 ?? And yes I not yet touched Little Fermat

Comment: Note that $2^6\equiv 2^3\equiv 1\mod 7$ is not such a big deal! =) Nice solution, by the way. I would upvote, but I have "capped".

Comment: @Praveen Surely the remainder theorem tells that the remainder upon dividing $f(x)$ by $x-a$ is equal to $f(a)$. If you want $x+1$, then we would need to have $x=6$, and it is difficult to write $2^{82}$ as a polynomial evaluated at $6$.